# Making a custom NSButton that has an on/off state, but still handles IBActions

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mouseevent, nsbutton

So I am creating a subclassed NSButton that has a custom look for the on/off state.

To do so, I overrided `-mouseDown` and `-mouseUp`, and modified the view accordingly.

Now in the view controller that owns the button, I have an `IBAction` connected to this custom button.

The problem is that when I overrided the `NSResponder` methods, the `IBAction` never gets called **unless** I call `[super mouseDown]` within the overrided `-mouseDown` method.

**But** if I call `[super mouseDown]`, the custom button doesn't receive the `-mouseUp` event (and the UI doesn't update back into the off/unpressed state).

I've tried a few things, but this seems like a common thing people would have customized, and it should be easier than I'm making it.

I was thinking of creating a block property on the custom button called `pressedAction`, and when the view controller is instantiated, set that block property on the button with the code I would have had in the `IBAction`.  Then inside of the custom button, I would just execute this block in the `-mouseUp` method

But that solution seems a little weird because to me a subclassed NSButton should be able to fire `IBActions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this a couple of ways in the past. Instead of overriding -mouseDown and -mouseUp I used the views layer and the NSCell property

```
isHighlighted
```

Your NSButton subclass would look like this

```
- (BOOL)wantsUpdateLayer
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)updateLayer
{
    if ([self.cell isHighlighted]) {
        self.layer.contents = [NSImage imageNamed:@"OnStateImage"];
    } else {
        self.layer.contents = [NSImage imageNamed:@"OffStateImage"];
    }
}
```

Or instead of subclassing NSButton you can subclass NSButtonCell and override
`- (void)drawBezelWithFrame:(NSRect)frame inView:(NSView *)controlView`

and again use the isHighlighted property

```
- (void)drawBezelWithFrame:(NSRect)frame inView:(NSView *)controlView {

    if (self.isHighlighted) {
        //Draw on State
    } else {
        //Draw off State
    }
}
```